# How to number the posts (ie #1, #2, #3) in a wp_query?

Tags: wp-query

What is the best way to display the appearance number of a post in a query?

For example, if a post is the first listed print #1. If it is third, print #3.

Any direction is appreciated!

Comment: start a counter before The Loop, display the value of the counter in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo('#' . $the_query->current_post + 1); // $the_query->current_post has the index
endwhile;
```